# Is the a way for SQLDelight to allow unrecognized expression?

Tags: mysql, kotlin, sqldelight

I use SQLDelight's MySQL dialect on my server. Recently I plan to migrate a table to combine many fields into a JSON field so the server code no longer needs to know the complex data structure. As part of the migration, I need to do something like this during **runtime** - when the sever sees a client with the new version, it knows the client won't access the old table anymore, so it's safe to migrate the record to new table.

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO new_table SELECT id, a, b, JSON_OBJECT('c', c, 'd', JSON_OBJECT(…)) FROM old_table WHERE id = ?;
```

The only problem is - Unlike [the SQLite dialect](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/dialects/sqlite/json-module/src/main/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/dialects/sqlite/json/module/JsonFunctions.kt), [the MySQL dialect](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/blob/master/dialects/mysql/src/main/kotlin/app/cash/sqldelight/dialects/mysql/grammar/MySql.bnf) doesn't recognize `JSON_OBJECT` or other JSON expressions, even though in this case it doesn't have to - no matter how complex the query is, the result is not passed back to Kotlin.

I wish I could add the feature by myself, but I'm pretty new to Kotlin. So my question is: is there a way to evade the rigid syntax check? I could also retrieve from old table, convert the format in Kotlin, then write to the new table, but that would take hundreds of lines of complex code, instead of just one `INSERT`.

Comment: I don't know about your specific case, but this sounds suspiciously like you're trying to create an [inner platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect), which often has greater costs than benefits.

Comment: Thanks @gidds I get what you mean. In my case the server doesn't need to know anything about the data except for this one-off migration. All logic happen on the client side. This is to avoid having to change server code and take care about back compatibility whenever a change happens on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your links you're on the alpha releases already, in alpha03 you *can* add currently unsupported behaviour by creating a local SQLDelight module (see [this](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/tree/master/sqldelight-gradle-plugin/src/test/custom-dialect) example) and adding the `JSON_OBJECT` to the functionType override. Also new function types are one of the easiest things to contribute up to SQLDelight so if you want it in the next release

Answer (score 0):

For the record I ended up using `CONCAT` with `COALESCE` as a quick and dirty hack to scrape the fields together as JSON.